# gdb during startup program exited with code 127

Tags: bash, c++, netbeans, gdb

I am using Ubuntu 17.04, I am having problem with gdb. I am using CLion and Netbeans for C++ programming, when I debug code, it's throwing me this error `During startup program exited with code 127.` I have tried every possible solution from SO, but couldn't get rid of this.

I have tried

1. setting SHELL env to `/bin/bash`
2. Installing 32 libs, these were already there `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 build-essential`
3. `readelf -l /usr/local/sbin/test | grep interpreter` this gives me this `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]` 
    Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021595/gdb-during-startup-program-exited-with-code-127

Can anyone here help me??

Comment: People probably *can* help you, but you can help yourself a lot by following the advice we gave you at the (now deleted) [other copy of this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401003/80216) — Say what you’re doing. What command did you type to get into `gdb`?  What program are you debugging?  Debug your program by other methods: cut out pieces until the problem goes away, then focus on the last thing you cut out.  Give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — a program, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  as short as you can possibly make it, that exhibits the same problem.   Tell us how you compiled your program, down to the C++ compiler command line (don’t just say what buttons you clicked in your IDE).   What is the output of `file`? And what is the complete output you’re getting from `gdb` — the [SO] question shows a “No such file or directory” error; are you getting that?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.